# Open source Telnet Java API

Tags: java, telnet

Is there an open source telnet API/library out there for Java (something like Python telnetlib)? I need to connect to a server using telnet and execute some commands from within a Java program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My preference is to use the Apache Commons-Net library. http://commons.apache.org/net/  It supports many client protocols, including Telnet.

I've used this in the past and it works quite well.

Comment: I took your suggestion and made something [simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988029/java-telnet-library/14098926#14098926) (and EXTREMELY limited in scope) for my use... might be handy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is worth considering using SSH protocol, instead of Telnet. Telnet is much less secure, for instance all the data is transmitted as plain text (including your passwords).

Comment: it's a windows machine that already has a telnet server, it's also in the internal network, so no outside access (no security concerns).

Answer (score 0):

Sure is.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtelnet/
(EDIT: Noted as crap.)

Here is an Apache project which is presumably much more handy:

http://commons.apache.org/net/

Comment: Lets see, last website update in 2003, last file update in 2003, and 2 negative votes with a comment saying its very bad. I don't think so

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that like 3 seconds after I posted it. ;)